# Maintain subsequence order in OrderBy

Tags: c#, sorting, ienumerable

Suppose I have a class with an integer `Day` property and an `IEnumerable<T>` of objects where the days are 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3 and 5 (in that order).

Is there a way to guarantee that the order of the subsequence where (for example) `o.Day == 3` is maintained from its elements' relative positions in the original list *without* requiring an explicit, custom implementation of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: What _subsequence_? I only see one `IEnumerable<T>` of objects.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think OP means these two 3 elements one after each other.

Comment: @golergka Exactly - a subsequence being an ordered subset of the initial sequence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`OrderBy` is documented as being [stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125552/what-is-the-meaning-of-stable-and-unstable-for-various-sorting-algorithms), if that is what you mean; so: you shouldn't need to do anything.

[`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements that have the same key.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to guarantee that the order of the subsequence where

Assuming you have class like this:

```
class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

and the sequence:

```
{ "A", 2 },
{ "B", 3 },
{ "C", 4 },
{ "D", 1 },
{ "E", 3 },
{ "F", 3 },
{ "G", 5 },
```

If you mean, will this:

```
sequence.Where(item => item.Day == 3)
```

produce the sequence, where items will be ordered like this: `B, E, F`, then the answer is "no, you nave no guarantee".

If your sequence is a `List<A>`, than ordering will be preserved (indeed, it will be preserved with LINQ to Objects, not only with lists).

If you sequence is `IQueryable<A>`, then the ordering may depend from the LINQ provider implementation, underlying data source and current expression tree, already contained in `IQueryable<A>`. So, in this case you should force ordering with `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I don't agree with your answer. If `sequence` is `IEnumerable<A>` then `sequence.Where(item => item.Day == 3)` will preserve the original order.

Comment: @user2266486: Yes, it will. `If your sequence is a List<A>, than ordering will be preserved` - did you read this?

Comment: The question explicitly states `IEnumerable<T>` - so only the `Enumerable` (not `Queryable`) methods are candidates here; also - the question is talking about `OrderBy`, not `Where`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: do you see any `OrderBy` anywhere except title?

Comment: @Dennis Yes I did. I don't agree with what you said just before 'the answer is "no, you nave no guarantee"'. Morover, the sequence doesn't need to be `List<A>`. `IEnumerable<A>` will suffice.

Comment: @Dennis the title is sufficient, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell: there's nothing about `OrderBy` in question's body. Unfortunately, OP didn't explain, what subsequence he mentioned exactly. About `IEnumerable<T>`/`IQueryable<T>`: suppose, you have method, accepting `IEnumerable<T>`, which calls `Where`/`OrderBy` etc. You can pass `IQueryable<T>` to this method, and `Queryable` extensions methods will be called. OP didn't tell anything about nature of his sequence. Am I missing something?